# Android talkback; how to disable announcing cell position and cell count?

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

When I have a recycler view with 12 items, when accessibility focus goes onto cell number 3, for example, talkback announces "Double tap to activate. Item 3 of 12".

I want to keep the action but stop it from announcing the item position and item count. How can I do this? I have tried to assign a delegate to the recycler view but not sure what to override in the delegate.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a functionality that should not be disabled: it lets people using Talkback know that they are in a list, how long is the list, which element is currently focused (are there more elements above/below).

Comment: It can be disabled, because sometimes you want to implement your own messages that tell the user that they are in a list and that the items are unique in some way, like a table of unique IDs does not need to announce the cell position. Have a look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/principles#collection. 
Your point is valid though. Im just saying it should be, and can be overriden, see my answer :)

Comment: Make sure the list can still be scrolled via Talkback after this change: setting collection info to null will remove these announcements, but will also break other behaviour, like automatically scrolling to the items not on screen when user reaches them.

Comment: You are right on that. It certainly does inhibit other collection related behaviour. I only explored this as an experiment. There must be a less destructive approach. Perhaps some properties off the CollectionInfo objet?

Comment: I have never been able to figure it out without breaking other functionality :/

Comment: The question is not "should I disable it or not" but "how to disable it".

Answer (score 2):

So I figured it out. An AccessibilityNodeInfo has a method called `SetCollectionInfo()`. CollectionInfo has properties like rowCont and columnCount.
I simply set the info to null.

Note, the below is xamarin:

```
    private class TabLayoutTabAccessibilityDelegate: View.AccessibilityDelegate
    {
        public override void OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfo info)
        {
            base.OnInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
            info.SetCollectionInfo(null);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It didn't help with `BottomNavigationView`. After reading my own content description, it adds: "tab ExampleTitle1 one of four".